# Issue with auto-complete widgets in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, widget

I am using an auto-complete widget in java script to show a list of available books in a store. The widget is working and I already saw the array of books in the console log but it does not show the list of the books in the auto-complete area. Any kind of guidance or sample code would be appreciated.

```
<p style="display: inline;"><b>Please Select Book:</b></p>
<input name="book" type="text" id="book_item" value="<?php echo $myArray['book_name']; ?>" />
<input name="book_id" type="hidden" id="book_item_id" value="" />
```

And the JavaScript is:

```
$(function () {

        var availableBooks =<?php echo json_encode($myArray) ?>;           
        console.log(availableBooks);   //I get all the books and their details here so jason array has no problem, problem starts at this point

        $("#book_item").autocomplete({
            open: function (e) {
                valid = false;
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#book_item_id").val(ui.item.id);
                valid = true;
            },
            close: function (e) {
                if (!valid)
                    $(this).val('');
            },
            source: availableBooks
        });

        $("#book_item").change(function () {
            if (availableBooks.indexOf($(this).val()) == -1) {
                $(this).val("");
                $("#book_item_id").val("");
            }
        });
    });
```

And here is how the array looks like, there is nothing special about the array, just details of the book. It is quit longer than below but showed some part of it as example:

```
book_name: "Elmo"
book_status: "active"
product_id: "1554345CCD1"
```

Comment: could you also provide a sample of the array data you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example Code

```
$(function () {
//Start
 var availableBooks =[{
"label": "Elmo",
"book_status": "active",
"value": "1554345CCD1"}]; 

$("#book_item").autocomplete({
source: availableBooks
});

//End of line.
});
```

The above code works... Noticed I changed the label, value to say label value because that is what the UI is looking for.
[image: fiddle]
jsfiddle.net/3nkut7o6

Comment: I have already tried above code, but still it does not show the auto-complete.

Comment: Maybe there is CSS hiding the results on your site? It does create a Unordered List (UL) Element.

Comment: You are correct, it seems that the issue was the way I was defining the variable. The variable that is holding the Jason array's data, need to be array itself too. Thank you very much for your time and guidance.